# Mongoose error('creator.username': ValidatorError: Path `creator.username` is required)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am using next.js and MongoDB to create posts and save them in MongoDB database. I have form inputs which accept title, description and user name of the creator and I have API routes that receive HTTP request from front end and create new post with the info provided. I am getting this error when doing that.

```
  description: ValidatorError: Path `description` is required.
        at validate (C:\Users\User\Desktop\nextjs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1270:13)
        at C:\Users\User\Desktop\nextjs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1253:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\Users\User\Desktop\nextjs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1198:14)
        at C:\Users\User\Desktop\nextjs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2545:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'description',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
```

When I try it with Postman it works. I understand that the error is saying that I am not providing the required information. But I did provide all of them. I can even `console.log` all of these required fields. Here is the code

```
import connectDB from "../../connectDB";

import Posts from "../../models/Posts";

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  connectDB();
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { username, title, description } = req.body;

    const newPost = await Posts.create({
      creator: {
        username,
      },
      title,
      description,
    });
    res.status(200).json({ newPost });
  } else if (req.method === "GET") {
    const allPosts = await Posts.find({});
    res.status(200).json({ allPosts });
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({ msg: "This http request method is not supported." });
  }
};

export default handler;
```

Here is how I am sending HTTP request to that route with required infos.

```
  const data = {
      title: inputVals.title.value,
      description: inputVals.description.value,
      username: "Fictitious Name",
    };
    e.preventDefault();
    const resp = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
    const newUser = await resp.json();
```

Like I said it worked when I tried the same thing with Postman.

Comment: Could you add Post model code to understand Post structure and  validation?

Comment: I found the solution. It turned out it was because I didn't add ``` headers :{"Content-Type":"application/json"}```. I don't know what it does but after adding that it did work. I usually use axios and none of these things are needed when using that. Thank you anyway.